# Why does this comparison to sizeof fail?

Tags: c, double

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if(sizeof(double) > -1)
        printf("M");
    else
        printf("m");
    return 0;
}
```

Size of `double` is greater than -1, so why is the output `m`?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `sizeof(double)` is of type `size_t`, which is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type of at least 16 bits. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-sizeof-Operator) for info on `sizeof` in C. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Important-Data-Types.html) for more info on `size_t`

The `-1` gets converted to an unsigned type for the comparison (`0xffff...`), which will always be bigger than `sizeof(double)`.

To compare to a negative number, you can cast it like this: `(int)sizeof(double) > -1`. Depending on what your objective is, it may also be better to compare to `0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has implementation defined behavior: `sizeof(double)` has type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type with at least 16 bits.

If this type is smaller than `int`, for example if `size_t` has 16 bits and `int` 32 bits, the comparison would be true because `size_t` would be promoted to `int` and the comparison would use signed int arithmetics.

Yet on most current platforms, `size_t` is either the same as `unsigned` or even larger than `unsigned`: the rules for evaluating the expression specify that the type with the lesser rank is converted to the type with the higher rank, which means that `int` is converted to the type of `size_t` if it is larger, and the comparison is performed using unsigned arithmetics. Converting `-1` to an unsigned type produces the largest value of this type, which is guaranteed to be larger than the size of a `double`, so the comparison is false on these architectures, which is alas very confusing.

I have never seen an architecture with a `size_t` type smaller than `int`, but the C Standard allows it, so your code can behave both ways, depending on the characteristics of the target system.